# Using "com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap", can I draw a route as I can on maps.google.com?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I expected it to be possible to get directions/draw a route between two points using Google Maps for Android (please note: Google Maps, NOT Google Navigation).

I just got the "com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap" (using MapFragment) to work, but I don't see any methods for drawing/getting a route between two points. So I am suspecting that this cannot be done.

Can someone verify or deny this? =)

PS: I know about "Google Navigation". It works to use an Intent to get a route there, but the problem is I cannot get it to be "inline" in my app, which in a way isn't ideal. So I was looking at Maps instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I don't see any methods for drawing/getting a route between two points. So I am suspecting that this cannot be done.

Use [a `Polyline`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lines#polylines) to draw the route.

"Getting a route" was not part of Maps V1 and is not part of Maps V2. You will have to find some Web service that will give you route information.

Also, I strongly encourage you to have qualified legal counsel review the terms and conditions for using Maps V2, to confirm that what you are trying to do is within the bounds of that agreement, which has specific clauses related to providing navigation assistance.

Comment: I will try the PolyLine approach... =)

Answer (score -1):

Getting a Route is discussed by Google Developers using API V2..API V1 is really not the proper answer to do it..Here is the API V2 code

```
public void setupLine(LatLng startLocation){
     //set up path
     PolylineOptions line=new PolylineOptions().add(startLocation).add(startLocation).color(mLineColour);
     mPath=mMap.addPolyline(line);
     mPath.setGeodesic(true);

     //Add 2 points
      pathPoints=new ArrayList<LatLng>(2);
      pathPoints.add(startLocation);//origin
      pathPoints.add(startLocation);//destination - updated later
    }

private void updateLine(LatLng position){
      //replace location
      pathPoints.set(1, position);

      //assign new points to path
      mPath.setPoints(pathPoints);

    }
```